# neo4j sink connector - Avro - unknown magic byte

Tags: neo4j, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am facing the below error.while adding the neo4j sink connector in confluent platform.

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException:
>   JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload"
>   fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to
>   deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your
>   converter configuration.  at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:359)

please check the below configuration part:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/Neo4j-Sink-Connect-book/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{

    "topics": "pls.bookneo",
    "connector.class": "streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "neo4j.server.uri": "bolt://localhost:7687",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.username": "neo4j",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.password": "*****"

}'
```

Updated changes as follows :
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/Neo4j-Sink-Connect-book/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{

```
"topics": "pulseTest.bookneo",
"connector.class": "streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector",
"key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081", 
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081", 
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
"value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
"neo4j.server.uri": "bolt://localhost:7687",
"neo4j.authentication.basic.username": "neo4j",
"neo4j.authentication.basic.password": "pulse",
"neo4j.encryption.enabled": false,
"neo4j.topic.cdc.schema": "pulseTest.bookneo"
```

}'

now facing the issue :

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic pulseTest.bookneo to Avro: 
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

Now,My connector is running properly but the node is created blank in neo4j.

curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/Neo4j-Sink-Connect-projectp/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{

```
"topics": "projectsp",
"connector.class": "streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": false,
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"errors.tolerance": "all",
"neo4j.server.uri": "bolt://localhost:7687",
"neo4j.authentication.basic.username": "neo4j",
"neo4j.authentication.basic.password": "pulse",
"neo4j.encryption.enabled": false,
"neo4j.topic.cypher.projectsp": " MERGE (p:projects{projectname:coalesce(event.projectname,0),count:coalesce(event.count,0)})  "
```

}'

this is my cypher query :
" MERGE (p:projects{projectname:coalesce(event.projectname,0),count:coalesce(event.count,0)})  "

[I have attached the data coming from the topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iuKr.png)

Comment: Your error is not specific to neo4j. What research did you do for it?

Comment: I am adding the configuration on confluent for neo4j sink connectors.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the JsonConverter in your `key` too, so need to specify `schemas.enable` there as well:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/Neo4j-Sink-Connect-book/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "topics": "pls.bookneo",
    "connector.class": "streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "neo4j.server.uri": "bolt://localhost:7687",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.username": "neo4j",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.password": "*****"

}'
```

To learn more about converters see https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/

Answer (score 0):

> Unknown magic byte!

Your topic doesn't contain Avro data that was produced by a Confluent client, so the deserializer fails

You can verify the same thing by using Kafka avro console consumer